# Why does it say the Israelites chose Jeroboam as king of Israel in 2 Kings 17?

Tags: prophecy, 2-kings, solomon

2 Kings 17:21 NLT

> For when the Lord tore Israel away from the kingdom of David, ***they chose Jeroboam son of Nebat as their king***. Then Jeroboam drew Israel away from following the Lord and made them commit a great sin.

But earlier on its clear that it was God himself who had chosen Jeroboam through his prophet Ahijah because of the sins of Solomon's house

1 Kings 11:31 NLT

> Then he said to Jeroboam, "Take ten of these pieces, for this is what the Lord, the God of Israel, says: '***I am about to tear the kingdom from the hand of Solomon, and I will give ten of the tribes to you!***

God had clearly warned Solomon about idolatry which it seems the warnings had fallen on deaf ears

1 Kings 11:10 NLT

> He had warned Solomon specifically about worshiping other gods, but Solomon did not listen to the Lord's command.

Why then does the narrative imply that it was the people who had chosen Jeroboam rather than God?

Answer (score 0):

God can use anyone, good or evil, to accomplish His will. God had decided to split 10 tribes to follow Jeroboam (1 King 11:31-35), He would stirred up these 10 tribes to chose Jeroboam as king (2 King 17:21)

Answer (score 0):

Surely the answer is that both explanations can be combined into one.
God chose Jeroboam by prompting the people to choose Jereboam.
If the prompting was taking place at the unconscious level, they would think of it as their own decision.
(I believe this happens much more frequently than we can ever imagine)